# MVVM and initialization of view model properties in view model constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I use the GalaSoft MvvmLight library as part of a project and have a TabControl in my view who's tab index is defined through data binding like this:

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding TabIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
...
</TabControl>
```

In my view model I have defined the TabIndex property like this:

```
private int _tabIndex;
public int TabIndex
{
  get { return _tabIndex; }
  set { Set(() => TabIndex, ref _tabIndex, value); }
}
```

Now in the constructor of the view model, I set the initial value for the tab index like this:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
  _tabIndex = 2;
}
```

This seems to work fine, but I have lately seen some cases where it looks like the value of "SelectedIndex" does not reflect the initial value of "TabIndex". I have seen log entries where "TabIndex" has been set to -1 which is not possible from the view model, so my only explanation is that an uninitialized value from the view has been passed to the view model.

As I have not been able to reproduce the scenario locally, I have an uneasy feeling that there is some form of races condition going on here that I am not aware of.

So my question is: Is it OK to initialize my property in the view model through the field like I have done, or should I always set it through the property setter so as to trigger the PropertyChanged event?

Comment: My rule is to always use the Property instead of the field. There's a reason it's there (raising the event or doing some calculation, you never know).

Comment: Why do you need to keep track of the `TabIndex` in the view model? That looks like **view** code to me, which should be kept in the view, **not** the view model. @NahuelIanni is right, set the **property** instead of the field.

Comment: I do more with the TabIndex in my application than what I included in my example here, so I need to have it in the view model. But that's beside the point. I would like to understand if initializing my property this way is a problem, and if it is, then preferably why it is a problem.

Comment: Try to use the propertyName instead, I have like this with no issues so far, private int _tabIndex;
public int TabIndex
{
  get { return _tabIndex; }
  set { Set(() => nameof(TabIndex), ref _tabIndex, value); }
}